# When using the search feature in Windows Explorer, what is the difference between `kind` and `type`?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

When using the search feature in Windows Explorer, what is the difference between `kind` and `type`?

For example, we might search for `kind:=music`

Answer (score 2):

Open Windows Explorer and the Search tab so you can see the options. Within Explorer Search, "Kind" is the description of the item (calendar, contact, document, email and so o).  Under Other Properties is Type and that is File Extension description.

Comment: `kind:document` would bring back Excel, Word, Text files etc... `type:Excel` would only return .XLS, .XLSX, .XLSM etc...

Comment: In addition, this page shows all the options available https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference

Comment: I'm not sure about **Type**, but I beleive it matches on the text description associated with each file extension. **Kind** is a "roll-up" categorization where extensions are associated with a Kind in the Registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap`